# Setting App Engine mapreduce shard size

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

Does the App Engine Mapreduce API decide compute shard size according to its own logic in the final reduce job?

I am using the App Engine mapreduce API and have supplied the `shard_size`
kwarg to set my mapreduce shard size.

The shard size is particularly important in my mapreduce job because I don't want to batch too many results into any one given execution of the final step of my reduce function.  In other words, I'm hardcoding the shard size to evenly divide the users up according to an external constraint on the system.

The map job seems to shard out just fine, but the reducer uses only a fraction of the shards I've designated.

Here is a rough outline of the sort of code I am dealing with:

```
SHARD_SIZE = 42

def map_fun(entity):
  shard_key = random.randint(1, SHARD_SIZE)
  yield (
    shard_key,
    db.model_to_protobuf(entity).SerializeToString().encode('base64')
  )

def reduce_fun(key, entities):
  batch = []
  for entity in entities:
    #check for stuff
    batch.append(entity)
  expensive_side_effect(batch)


class MyGreatPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
  def run(self, *args, **kw):
    yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
      'label'
      'path.to.map_fun',
      'path.to.reduce_fun',
      'mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader',
      'mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter',
      mapper_params={
        'entity_kind': 'path.to.entity',
        'queue_name': 'coolQueue'
      },
      reducer_params={},
      shard_size = SHARD_SIZE
    )
```

`map_fun` specifically assigns each entity a shard that is determined randomly according to the shard size.  I'm confused about why my reducer would have fewer shards than `SHARD_SIZE` given that there are many entities and it is exceedingly unlikely that the same integers were picked repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzling over what you're doing here. Using the map phase to group stuff onto a small, sharded key, later processing those keys at reduce time looks odd. You're going to end up with too much work to do per key, even if you do engage as many reduce workers as you do mapper workers.

The 'batch' being processing is randomly arbitrary, so I assume that `expensive_side_effect()` isn't dependent on the content of the batch. Why not do that work instead at map time, emitting something that a reduced could pass through to the output writer?